# separation of quotient space

Tags: general-topology

I found quotient space on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space, I had seen a property that I don't know how I can prove it:

$X/\sim$ is a $T_1$ space if and only if every equivalence class of $\sim$ is closed in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

A topological space $\,Y\,$ is $\;T_1\;$ iff every singleton $\,\{y\}\;,\;y\in Y\;$ , is closed (yes, I know the usual definition is another one. This is an equivalent one).

Well, what are the *points* in the quotient space $\,X/\sim\;$  and how's the topology on this space defined...?

Comment: $[x]$ is closed in $X/\sim$ by its Hausdorff. If $p$ is quotient map. Then $[x]$ is closed in $X/\sim$ iff $p^{-1}([x])$ is closed in $X$

Comment: but it isn't obvious

Comment: I'm not sure what "isn't obvious", @Muniain, but it doesn't matter: yes, in general things must be proved.

Comment: Your first comment: what/who is Hausdorff? I can't see anywhere such an assumption, and even if $\,X\,$ is Hausdorff: how from there can you conclude an equivalence class is closed?

Comment: oh, sorry. From $X/\sim$ is $T_1$ iff $[x]$ is closed in $X/\sim$, then $p^{-1}([x])$ is closed in $X$

Comment: Can you give me a proof or material that I can read?